# Windows Phone Push live tile image URL

Tags: push-notification, push, live-tile

I'm working on a notification push server and want to push a live tile with an image URL (external server).

The problem is that I can't get it to show as BackgroundImage on the applicatoin tile. As far as I understand the documentation it should be possible as long as the URL is valid, not https, some size restrictions, etc.

I comply with all the restrictions given, but can't get my image from the external URL to show on the tile. Local files work though. I'm searching for hours. Can anybody tell me if it's possible or did some rules change since mango or something?

URL restrictions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx#urls

Answer (score 1):

And of course; as soon as I submitted the ticket I found the 'ListOfAllowedDomains' that should be set to the channel.